# Stopping an active Testcafe run

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, automated-tests, testcafe

I try to add a stop function to the Testcafe run. I start Testcafe with:

```
let testcafe = null;
let testcafeprom = null;

    testcafeprom = createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
        .then(tc => {
            testcafe     = tc;
            const runner = testcafe.createRunner();
            return runner
                .src([__basedir + '/tests/temp.js'])
                .browsers(myBrowser)
                //.browsers('browserstack:Chrome')
                .screenshots(__basedir +'/allure/screenshots/', true)
                .reporter(['uistatusreporter', {name: 'allure',output: 'test/report.json'}])
                .run();
        })
        .then(failedCount => {
            testcafe.close();
            startReportGenerator();
            capcon.stopCapture(process.stdout);
            console.log("Testcafe Ende");


            if(failedCount>0){
                res.sendStatus(400);
                console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
                //res.statusCode = 400; //BadRequest 400
                /*
                res.json({
                    success: 'failed',
                    fails: failedCount
                });
                */
            }else{
                //res.statusCode = 200; //BadRequest 400
                res.sendStatus(200);
                console.log('All success');
                /*
                res.json({
                    success: 'ok',
                    fails: failedCount
                });
                */
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            testcafe.close();
            console.log('Tests failed: Testcafe Error');
            console.log(error);
            res.sendStatus(401);

        });
```

Then I added a function to stop the run:

```
router.get('/stopit', async (req, res) => {

    testcafeprom.cancel();
    res.sendStatus(200);

});
```

As I understand is that createTestCafe will return a promise and in all to stop the promise I call `testcafeprom.cancel();` or `testcafeprom.stop();`

But the browser is running and running. A simple `testcafe.close();` will stop Testcafe complete. But I want to stop it and not shoot it down.

Any suggestion to stop it a better way?

Update:
I have also tested the way to make the runner as promise:

```
    createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
        .then(tc => {
            testcafe     = tc;
            const runner = testcafe.createRunner();
            testcafeprom =  runner
                .src([__basedir + '/tests/temp.js'])
                .browsers(myBrowser)
                //.browsers('browserstack:Chrome')
                .screenshots(__basedir +'/allure/screenshots/', true)
                .reporter(['uistatusreporter', {name: 'allure',output: 'test/report.json'}])
                .run();

            return testcafeprom;

        })
```

Adding also

```
await testcafeprom.cancel();
```

This will have exact the same result as `testCafe.close()`, means everything is shoot down without any response. Iam confused.

And finally I tried:

```
let runner = null;
    createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338, void 0, true)
        .then(testcafe => {
            runner = testcafe.createRunner();
        })
        .then(() => {
            return runner
                .src([__basedir + '/tests/temp.js'])
                .browsers(myBrowser)
                //.browsers('browserstack:Chrome')
                .screenshots(__basedir +'/allure/screenshots/', true)
                .reporter(['uistatusreporter', {name: 'allure',output: 'test/report.json'}])
                .run()
                .then(failedCount => {
                    //testcafe.close();
                    startReportGenerator();
                    capcon.stopCapture(process.stdout);
                    console.log(`Finished. Count failed tests:${failedCount}`);
                    //process.exit(failedCount);
                    res.sendStatus(200);
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            startReportGenerator();
            capcon.stopCapture(process.stdout);
            console.log(error);
            //process.exit(1);
            res.sendStatus(401);
        });
```

But here is the same. If I call await `runner.stop()` it looks like that the command will kill the whole process and nothing comes back to the promise.

Is this such a secret how to stop a running TestCafe instance or is the secret that the whole process is shoot down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say precisely why you face an issue since I cannot debug your project. However, you are correct when you use `cancel` to stop test execution. The `cancel` method stops tests execution and closes the browser, but it does not stop TestCafe. This means that you can use the `run` method again, and it will start test execution and open browsers again.

I created an example to demonstrate that this approach works.

Test code:

```
fixture `fixture`
    .page `http://example.com`;

for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    test(`test A ${i}`, async t => {
        await t.click('h1');
    });
}
```

Testcafe start code:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');

(async () => {
    const testCafe = await createTestCafe();

    let timeout;

    const runner = testCafe.createRunner();

    const runPromise = runner
        .src('test.js')
        .browsers('chrome')
        .run();

    const cancelPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            runPromise.cancel();

            resolve('canceled');
        }, 20000);
    });

    let value = await Promise.race([runPromise, cancelPromise]);

    if (value === 'canceled')
        console.log('test execution was canceled')

    value = await runner.run();

    console.log(`${value} failed tests`);

    await testCafe.close();
})();
```